# How to avoid a global object for a database in Python/Kivy

Tags: python, global-variables, kivy

To whom it may concern,

I have a Python class which contains a database, and has all the functionality I need - checked all from the command prompt.  Now I am trying to build a Kivy shell around it - to make it more user friendly and visually pleasing.

I managed by defining an instance of the database class as a global object :-S  So although I have accomplished my task, I am far from delighted.  I know, one should avoid global variables more than plague.

Can anyone suggest me a way around it?  Where to define the first instance of my database, and how to pass it among widgets?

I am showing a significantly reduced skeleton of my program below for discussion which will hopefully develop.

main.py:

```
from kivy.app   import App

from rootwidget import *
from mainmenu   import *
from editentry  import *

from database   import *  #  <----= import the database class I want to work on

from kivy.lang  import Builder
Builder.load_file("rootwidget.kv")
Builder.load_file("mainmenu.kv")
Builder.load_file("editentry.kv")

class DataBaseApp(App):
  def build(self):  
    return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  DataBaseApp().run()
```

Everything is standard Python/Kivy coding here, except the `import database`, which imports my database.  Database is stripped to bare bones too:

database.py:

```
class DataBase:
  entries = []
```

I have three widgets, the `rootwidget` (`ScreenManager`) with two children (of type `Screen`), `mainmenu` and `editentry`.

Their definitions follow:

rootwidget.kv:

```
#: kivy 1.9.0

<RootWidget>:
  name: "RootWidget_ScreenManager"

  MainMenu:
  EditEntry:
```

and rootwidget.py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
  pass
```

mainmenu.kv:

```
#: kivy 1.9.0

<MainMenu>:
  name: "MainMenu_Screen"

  BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
      text: "Main Menu"

    Button:
      text:  "Go to I/O"
      on_release:
        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        root.manager.current = "EditEntry_Screen"
```

mainmenu.py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MainMenu(Screen):
  pass
```

editentry.kv:

```
#: kivy 1.9.0

<EditEntry>:
  name: "EditEntry_Screen"

  BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
      text: "Edit Entry"

    Button:
      text:  "Go back to main menu"
      on_release:
        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        root.manager.current = "MainMenu_Screen"
```

and editentry.py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class EditEntry(Screen):
  pass
```

Hence, my question: where to instantiate the `DataBase` class?  I made a several attempts, one was to make the first instance at the `App` level, and then pass it as an argument to constructor to the `RootWidget`.  That worked but I could not pass it from the `RootWidget` to its children `MainMenu` and `EditEntry`.  Defining it at `RootWidget` level didn't help much because I still could not pass it to its children.  And if I define it at the children level, I am unable to pass from one child to another, say from `MainMenu` to `EditEntry`.

Any suggestion / help is appreciated

Cheers

Comment: What about creating an instance at the `App` level and getting it using static `kivy.app.App.get_running_app` function?

Comment: Woo - hoo!!!  That was it man, you saved my day - thanks.  :-)  Now I can do some refactoring